# Is there a way to move customization and data from one D365 instance to another instance residing on a completely separate tenant?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We have a requirement to transfer D365 instance along with customization and data from current domain to another O365 instance/setup.

Currently, the client has the D365 instance running on one tenant say "abc.onmicrosoft.com". And the O365 instance running on another instance i.e. "pqr.onmicrosoft.com".

Now, we would like to merge these two instances and keep only one.
We're planning to take backup of the D365 instance, take new CRM instance at the "pqr.onmicrosoft.com" instance, and take restore the backup there.
Is it possible?

Or any other ideas to achieve these things?

Comment: "Merge" or "Overwrite"?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to submit a request to Microsoft to move your CRM instance from one domain to the other.